# How to check that all list items are odd and bigger than 10?

Tags: haskell

I need to check if a list only contains odd numbers, bigger than 10.
This is what I did.

```
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f xs= [x |x<-xs, x >10,  odd x]
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: You might have come from another language, one that will automatically convert an empty list to a False boolean value. Haskell does not do that on its own, and the tentative body of your function returns a *list* instead of a boolean value. You could use the `null` library function. BTW when you say "it does not work", you are expected to provide the full error message, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `[x |x<-xs, x >10,  odd x]` you're making up a list of `Int`s, a `[Int]`, not a `Bool`ean. For instance you can verify that
`[x | x <- [1..20], x > 10, odd x]` is the list `[11,13,15,17,19]`. So it does contain the numbers that you want, but how do you tell that those are all of the numebrers in `xs`?

You could certainly equate that list to `xs` itself, and that would work:

```hs
f xs = xs == [x |x<-xs, x >10,  odd x]
```

This way the `==` ensures that when you only take odd numbers greater than 10 from `xs` you get back exactly `xs`, meaning that all numbers satisfy the predicate.

Maybe this is the mistake you were looking for.

I'm not sure whether this solution traverses `xs` twice (once to extract the entries satisfying the predicate, and once to check for equality) or not. It looks very simple, so I can't help but think that the list is traversed only once.

---

Anyway, another strategy is to stick to your request: you want `all` numbers `x` from the list `xs` for which `odd x` and `x > 10` are both `True`:

```hs
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f xs = all (\x -> odd x && x > 10) xs
```

By noticing that both sides have a trailing `xs`, you can reduce the definition:

```hs
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f = all (\x -> odd x && x > 10)
```

And that lambda, if you want, could be define more succintly as `(odd & (> 10))`, thus getting

```hs
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f = all (odd & (> 10))
```

provided you `import Control.Monad (liftM2)` and define

```hs
(&) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
(&) = liftM2 (&&)
```

Comment: But what if the input is [4,11] ?

Comment: @jpmarinier, thanks, I had terribly misinterpreted the question.

Comment: yes, `xs` is traversed only once, because of laziness. e.g. `f [1,2,3]` is equivalent to `1>10 && odd 1 && 1==1 && 2>10 && odd 2 && 2==2 && 3>10 && odd 3 && 3==3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your type signature mentions that the function returns a boolean value, but your proposed body returns a list of numbers. Haskell has no automatic conversions such as Lisp.

Should you wish to stick to pedestrian code, you could get the sublist of offending numbers, and just check that the sublist is empty.

```
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f xs = let offenders = [x | x <- xs, x <= 10  ||  even x]
       in   (null offenders)
```

Note that due to the laziness of the language runtime, evaluation of `offenders` stops as soon as we find a first element.

Should you want something a bit more haskell-ish, you can use the `sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)` polymorphic library function to turn a list of predicates into a single function returning a list of boolean values, then pass that list to `and`. That checks one number.

Then use `all` to apply these checks to all numbers in the input list. Like this:

```
f2 :: [Int] -> Bool
f2 = all (and . sequence [(>10), odd])
```

### Explanation:

To understand how exactly the `sequence` function gets specialized by the compiler, one can use the [TypeApplications](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/type-application) language extension.

With the extension enabled, given 3 type arguments, expression `sequence @tt @tm @ta` maps tt to the Traversable instance, tm to the Monad instance and ta to argument type a.

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :type sequence
 sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XTypeApplications
 λ>
```

We start with the easiest part, mapping `tt` to lists and `ta` to `Bool`, leaving `tm` undefined as an underscore _:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type  sequence @[]  @_  @Bool
 sequence @[] @_ @Bool :: Monad _ => [_ Bool] -> _ [Bool]
 λ>
```

Now, if we assign `tm` to “function of an Int variable”, we have the whole picture:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type  sequence @[]  @((->)Int)  @Bool
 sequence @[] @((->)Int) @Bool :: [Int -> Bool] -> Int -> [Bool]
 λ>
```

The last type can be interpreted as `[Int -> Bool] -> (Int -> [Bool])`, that is, function `sequence` transforming a list of predicates into a single function returning a list of boolean values.

Comment: You could also consider `all (\x -> all ($x) [(>10), odd])`. I think it's a bit easier to read, though I know these things are fairly subjective. I guess if you're willing to have a point, though, it's hard not to just go `all (\x -> x>10 && odd x)`.

Comment: `f2 = all ((&&) <$> (>10) <*> odd)` is another option that relies less on compiler cleverness to be efficient.

Comment: @DanielWagner Well, the predicate list is clearly arbitrary, so I wanted to be able to have that predicate list as the leftmost argument of f. But your first formula provides that more elegantly. Let's just say I wanted to have a go at point-free programming for once.